# How to add html inside textarea?

Tags: html, textarea

I want to enter an html code in the textarea after you change the div1 and div2 position by button click. Any changes I make to html div parent should also be changed in textarea. I have no idea how to do it?
The purpose is to send a changed div parent in the database..

```
<style>
#parent{
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: grey;
}
#div1{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
#div2{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

<button type="button"  onclick="myFunctionSwitch()" >Chenge texareaHTML</button>

<form>
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="showhtml">
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
</textarea>
</form>


<script>

function myFunctionSwitch() {

  document.getElementById("div1").remove();
  document.getElementById("div2").remove();

  var x = document.createElement('div');
  x.id = 'div2';
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(x);
  var y = document.createElement('div');
  y.id = 'div1';
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(y);


  document.getElementById("showhtml").innerHTML = x + y;
}

</script>
```

Comment: would you plz vote my answer up if it helps? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181151/add-ondrop-ondragover-to-the-new-created-element-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id=container>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("showhtml").innerHTML = x + y;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("showhtml").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
```

**Here is the working code:**

```js
function myFunctionSwitch() {

  document.getElementById("div1").remove();
  document.getElementById("div2").remove();

  var x = document.createElement('div');
  x.id = 'div2';
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(x);
  var y = document.createElement('div');
  y.id = 'div1';
  document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(y);


  document.getElementById("showhtml").innerHTML = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
}
```

```css
#parent{
width: 50px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: grey;
}
#div1{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
#div2{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
</div>

<button type="button"  onclick="myFunctionSwitch()" >Chenge texareaHTML</button>

<form>
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="showhtml">
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Alireza Yazdandoost thanks for your help. I need another detail.
How do I get HTML and STYLE in "showhtml" (textarea)?
Example: <div id = "div1" style = "width: 150px;"> </ div>
Currently I get only HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you enter html into your `textarea`, it will be escape and not be parsed as html element.

The only way to do what you want is usign `contenteditable` attribute.

View this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).